# How can I make a textbox readonly for certain users in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a text box on my web page and I want to make it `readonly` for certain users in PHP. The following is the code of the textbox which is populated from an array retrieved from database.

```
<td width="130" align="right" valign="top" nowrap>
    <label for="descr">Name</label>:
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="descr" id="descr" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_product['descr'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" size="50">
```

I want only certain users to only read the value and not be able to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

textareas (and other inputs) have a readonly attribute.  You can just put it in the tag for those users that meet the condition.  XML compliant: `readonly="readonly"`

Comment: <td width="130" align="right" valign="top" nowrap><label for="descr">Name</label>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="descr" id="descr" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_product['descr'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" size="50">

Comment: where exactly should i put that and how do I check the user ?

Comment: Where is the condition of whether or not it should be readonly stored?

Comment: I did not put it, anytime I try to do it, it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

You may add the [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) attribute to the input element.

However, be aware that some clients might try to change the value when submitting the form anyway, so you **must** do server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

ok. so you know when users are read-only,

so for those users before the close of the input tag add:

```
<?=($readonly==true)?'readonly':''?>
```

**UPDATE**
should have set previously if the user is a readonly user or not with a variable suchas:

```
$readonly = true;
```

or

```
$readonly = false;
```

so your td would be:

```
    <td width="130" align="right" valign="top" nowrap>
       <label for="descr">Name</label>:
       </td> 
       <td>
       <input type="text" name="descr" id="descr" 
        value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_product['descr'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" 
        size="50" 
        <?=($readonly==true)?'readonly':''?> />
```

Comment: <td width="130" align="right" valign="top" nowrap><label for="descr">Name</label>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="descr" id="descr" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_product['descr'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" size="50"> This is the actual code. plz elaborate more for me. I am a very novice user to PHP and HTML